# Clear text in textbox upon clicking it

Tags: vba, textbox

I have text in a textbox, which says "NEW NAME HERE"

Is it possible with in VBA to clear this text as soon as the user clicks in that textbox?

If so could anyone please let me know how?

THANKS-

Comment: you can edit your question and add details rather than posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the TextBox is named `TextBox1`, the following should work

```
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old post, but I just stumbled upon it, and thought I'd add an answer.
Maybe someone will find it useful some day `:-)`

I would check the current value before clearing the content. That way it clears the content when you first click it, but if you click it again later (to edit the name perhaps) it does nothing, allowing edits without having to start over.

Assuming the TextBox is named `TextBox1` and the placeholder text is `NEW NAME HERE`, the following should work

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    If TextBox1.Text = "NEW NAME HERE" Then
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

To restore the placeholder text if the textbox is left empty:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Trim(TextBox1.Text) = "" Then
        TextBox1.Text = "NEW NAME HERE"
    End If
End Sub
```

Tested in Word 2010 VBA

Answer (score 1):

I tried it without the Handles part (like the other person who had answered) and that did nothing. I've confirmed the code below works for me.

```
Private Sub txtNewNameHere_GotFocus() Handles txtNewNameHere.GotFocus
    txtNewNameHere.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Hopefully this helps someone, even though this question is a bit old.

Comment: `Handles` does not work in VBA. Maybe [@J. Rusell](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1102936/j-russell) tried that in .NET.

Comment: Ah dang I barely noticed this comment, haven't needed to use stack for awhile.. Anywho, you're right, at the time I "helped" out I was probably using regular ol' .Net VB, not realizing until this last year the difference between that and VBA :/ -- I'll leave this bad answer up for posterity... Thanks for pointing that out though..

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Textbox1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Textbox1.MouseClick
    textbox1.clear()
End Sub
```

try this. i just this code in daniweb.