# Clearing textbox upon click

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I'm relatively new to VBA, and am working on a small database for my employer. I'm trying to create a text box that, when clicked, deletes the contents that I have put in it. For example, I have a text box that says "first" for them to put in the first name of a member. When they click it, I want my text to disappear so they can enter what they want. (The matter of it only executing once is easily solved with an if statement). I've taken a look at the following question, but neither answer worked for me;

[Clear text in textbox upon clicking it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068576/clear-text-in-textbox-upon-clicking-it)

The following code did nothing

```
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus()
TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

And the following code give me an "Expected, end of statement" compilation error on 'Handles';

```
Private Sub txtNewNameHere_GotFocus() Handles txtNewNameHere.GotFocus
txtNewNameHere.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Not sure why either of those did not work for me, but, as I said, I'm relatively new to this. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the name of the textbox, 'txtNewNameHere' ?

Comment: @nobillygreen: Are you sure you are doing it in VBA? For VBA see mkingston answer. For vb6 see Gimp's answer and for vb.net use the `Handles txtNewNameHere.GotFocus` as you have it in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will clear the text box on focus if it did not already have focus:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    TextBox1.Value = ""
End Sub
```

It will not clear the text box every time it is clicked. Does that help?

Comment: Perhaps this is because the TextBox is on a sheet, not on a form? maybe the OP can clarify which it is.

Comment: The text box is indeed in a form. This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the name for your textbox is 'Text1' The following event will do what you're looking for:

```
Private Sub Text1_GotFocus()
    If Me.Text1.Value = "First" Then
        Me.Text1.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

I always put the me. in front of the object to reference the form.

I was unclear if the name of your text box was 'TextBox1' or 'txtNewNameHere' from your above code examples so I just used a generic 'Text1' in the above code.

If you're unsure of what the Name of your textbox is yourself right click the text box and select 'properties'

Update:
Assumed that textbox was located in a form object.

Comment: Actually, this did NOT work for me... For some reason, the GotFocus method is never being called (I even put a MsgBox statement before the if to see if it was activating). I removed the frame that the text box was located in as I was thinking that I might be clicking on THAT instead of the actual text box. Still nothing.But, I did manage to get it to work with a MouseDown command. However, I would still like to know why your's isn't working for me.

Comment: This worked for me when I tried it.  It needs to be entered into the code for the sheet the box is on, not in a module.

Answer (score 1):

Even after all this time, this is one of the main results in google, so I'd like to share information about the matter that might make things easier for people who could reach the page in the future after a couple of hours on the matter:

The method below works only for unbounded controls:

```
Private Sub Text1_GotFocus()
If Me.Text1.Value = "First" Then
    Me.Text1.Value = ""
End If 
End Sub
```

What I did was to create a function that goes through all controls, checks if they are bounded, and if not bounded, attributes the default value:

NOTES ON THE FUNCTION BELOW:
1- I think "DefaultValue" is better then "", but that would work too.
2- The "Select case" is needed otherwise the .ControlSource property is not found.
3- You could check the bound of the control in each type if needed, I only had textboxes with bound.
4- The "Me.Refresh" makes bounded controls to be set to default, as long the bound is related to controls in the same form.

```
Function ClearControls(frm As Form)
Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl In frm.Controls
    Select Case ctrl.ControlType
            Case acTextBox
                If ctrl.ControlSource = Null Then
                    ctrl.Value = ctrl.DefaultValue
                End If
            Case acOptionGroup, acComboBox, acListBox
                ctrl.Value = Null
            Case acCheckBox
                ctrl.Value = False
        End Select
Next
Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

So, on the click event code I just called the ClearControls function as follows:

```
ClearControls Me
```

This also makes possible to re-use the function in other controls/events.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the below code to nullify / reset the values in the vba forms

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    TextBox1.Value = Null
    TextBox2.Value = Null
    TextBox3.Value = Null
    TextBox4.Value = Null
    End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to the community!
Try to increase your response, according to the conditions of the question. Remember, the field should be cleared only if the current value is "first". Another detail: Assigning the Null value to the Value property, will not clear the textbox.
Example:
Private Sub txtFirtName_Enter()
    If txtFirtName.Text = "First" Then
        txtFirtName.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtFirtName_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If txtFirtName.Text = "" Then
        txtFirtName.Text = "First"
    End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted a long time ago but if anybody finds themselves here, here's an updated one;

```
Private Sub Textbox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Textbox1.Click
        Textbox1.Text = ""
    End Sub
```